# "im Moment" versus "am Moment"

Tags: preposition

[DWDS shows both "am Moment" and "im Moment" in use.](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=zeit&q=am%20Moment)
Is it fair to say that "im Moment" refers to the present point in time, and "am Moment" refers to a point in time other than the current one? So it could be used in this way:

> **Im** Moment habe ich keine Schmerzen.

and

> **Am** Moment, als ich aufwachte, hatte ich keine Schmerzen.

or

> **Am** Moment, wenn ich aufwache, habe ich keine Schmerzen.

Comment: I'd say it is always "Im Moment", and I consider "am" at least assurance of not wrong, but there might some subtlety or regional variation which eludes me.

Comment: If "am Moment" is wrong, why is it so widely used? https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=zeit&q=am%20Moment

Comment: @user44591 the "an" comes from elsewhere: "Spaß an etwas", "an etwas scheitern", "an etw. (er)freuen".

Comment: Im Moment erfreue ich mich am Moment --> Currently I take pleasure in this moment as it happens

Comment: Neben dem Moment als kurzer Zeitspanne (Nu) gibt es auch ein Moment in Physik und Ingenieurswesen, am beliebtesten das Drehmoment mit seinem Schlüssel. Dieses wird aber auch selten mit "am" gebildet. "Er glänzte in der Prüfung beim Impuls, scheiterte aber am (Dreh-)Moment." wäre möglich.

Comment: It's important to consider the number of results in a usage database. In this case *im Moment* is used 2000 time more frequently than *am Moment*, so it's reasonable to assume that *am Moment* is only used under rather odd circumstances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For whatever reason, it's *am Montag, am Morgen, am Abend, am Tag,* but *in der Nacht, in dieser Woche, im Moment, in diesem Moment, im gleichen Moment, in der Sekunde, in der vierten Stunde*. Please forget about using "am Moment" in a temporal sense.

If you'd like to make a difference between the present point in time and a different point in time that you further describe, you can use:

> **Im Moment** habe ich keine Schmerzen.
> *or:* **In diesem Moment** habe ich keine Schmerzen.

vs.

> **In dem Moment**, als ich aufwachte, hatte ich keine Schmerzen.
> *or:* **In dem Moment**, wenn (*or:* in dem) ich aufwache, habe ich keine Schmerzen.

Just using *im Moment* works in both sentences above, too, but *in dem Moment*  puts a bit more stress on the fact that it is a particular moment that is described. For example, if you wanted to continue saying that the pain came back later, then *in dem Moment* is very fitting.

As you pointed out in the comments, there actually is [a context](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=zeit&q=am%20Moment) where "am Moment" is used, but it's not in a temporal sense:

> »Der Mann schaut nur, er **freut sich am Moment**.« (The man is just watching, he is **pleased with the moment** *or* **rejoicing in the moment** *or* **enjoying the moment**.)

"Sich an etwas freuen" (*or* "Spaß **an** etwas haben") means "to enjoy something".

> "Die Bühnenkunst scheitert am Moment." (Stagecraft fails at the moment.)

"An etwas scheitern" means "to fail at something". So this doesn't mean "Stagecraft is failing right now as we're talking", but it's a statement about *what* stagecraft is *failing at*.

Comment: Your insight has not only helped me to understand German better, but even my own native language of English, which usually obscures the distinction that German makes between am and im Moment. Which is why I could not observe the difference on my own, but which is so obvious when pointed out.